# Is it possible to create 2 or more docs in cosmosDB with 1 outputbinding

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

Need to create 2 docs in a CosmosDB container with Azure Function, is it possible to use just one out-binding? I supposed that alternative is using Cosmos DB client.

function.js

```
{
    "bindings": [{
            "name": "documents",
            "type": "cosmosDBTrigger",
            "direction": "in",
            "leaseCollectionName": "leases",
            "connectionStringSetting": "db_DOCUMENTDB",
            "databaseName": "db",
            "collectionName": "container1",
            "createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists": true
        },
        {
            "name": "inputDocumentOut",
            "type": "cosmosDB",
            "databaseName": "db",
            "collectionName": "container2",
            "createIfNotExists": false,
            "partitionKey": "{_partitionKey}",
            "connectionStringSetting": "db_DOCUMENTDB",
            "direction": "out"
        }
    ]
}
```

index.js

```
module.exports = async function(context, documents, inputDocumentOut) {

    context.log('JavaScript cosmos-trigger function processed a request.');

    if (!!documents && documents.length > 0) {
         // code ...
    }

    return {
        inputDocumentOut: [ doc1, doc2 ] // ???
    }

};
```

Comment: I think you'd need to use SDK calls directly for this

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just pass an array of documents to the output binding instead of a single one:

```
module.exports = async function(context, documents) {

    context.log('JavaScript cosmos-trigger function processed a request.');
    var documentsToSave = [];
    if (!!documents && documents.length > 0) {
         // code ...
         // maybe call documentsToSave.push({.. some document schema to save..});
    }

    context.bindings.inputDocumentOut = documentsToSave;
};
```